# Error when rendering a partial view in ASP.NET MVC 5

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

I am trying to return a page within another when an id is passed on to a controller.
But I get this error:

```
 Error executing child request for handler 'System.Web.Mvc.HttpHandlerUtil+ServerExecuteHttpHandlerAsyncWrapper'.
```

Views\Error_Summaries\Details.cshtml

```
  @{Html.RenderAction("FindAllDetails", new { bolnumber = Model.BOL });}
```

Error_SummariesController.cs

```
public ActionResult FindRelatedBols(string bolnumber)
{
    if (bolnumber == null)
    {
        return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
    }
    Error_Summaries error_Summaries = db.Error_Summaries.SingleOrDefault(r => r.BOL == bolnumber);
    if (error_Summaries == null)
    {
        return HttpNotFound();
    }
    return View("Views/Error_Details/Details");
}
```

Comment: That means, your code is crashing when trying to render the result of that action method. Check the Inner exception and it will tell you what the error is.

Comment: Also you probably want `return View("~/Views/Error_Details/Details.cshtml");`

Comment: If you are trying to render a partial view, you should use `PartialView` method: `return PartialView("/Error_Details/Details");`

Comment: All three comments helped so I don't know if somebody wants to make it an answer. I have one more question here  - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47638357/error-when-converting-list-to-ienumberable

Comment: You can self answer since you are the only one know what the exact problem was.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When checking the inner exception it showed that it was looking at the wrong action name. I had specified FindAllDetails instead FindRelatedBols. Also, the return path was wrong. And finally, I wasn't using the right Method name.

```
public ActionResult FindRelatedBols(string bolnumber)
{
    if (bolnumber == null)
    {
        return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
    }
    //var test = 
    //var qrytest = db.Error_Details.Where(r => r.BOL == bolnumber);
    //var details = qrytest.ToList();
    var details = db.Error_Details.Where(r => r.BOL == bolnumber).ToList();
    if (details == null)
    {
        return HttpNotFound();
    }
    return PartialView("~/Views/Error_Details/Index.cshtml", details);
}
```