# Error when converting List to IEnumerable

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I am trying to display the default index page for a model. But I get the below error.

> The model item passed into the dictionary is of type
>   'System.Collections.Generic.List 1[System.Boolean]', but this
>   dictionary requires a model item of type
>   'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[EDIWebsite.Models.Error_Details]'.

Controller

```
 public ActionResult FindRelatedBols(string bolnumber)
        {
            if (bolnumber == null)
            {
                return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
            }
            var error_Summaries = db.Error_Details.Select(r => r.BOL == bolnumber);
            if (error_Summaries == null)
            {
                return HttpNotFound();
            }
            return PartialView("~/Views/Error_Details/Index.cshtml",error_Summaries.ToList());
        }
```

View

```
@model IEnumerable<EDIWebsite.Models.Error_Details>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

<h2>Index</h2>

<p>
    @Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create")
</p>
<table class="table">
    <tr>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Source_System)
        </th>
.
.
.
            @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { /* id=item.PrimaryKey */ }) |
            @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { /* id=item.PrimaryKey */ }) |
            @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { /* id=item.PrimaryKey */ })
        </td>
    </tr>
}

</table>
```

Comment: You're passing it a `List<bool>`, but it's expecting an `IEnumerable<Error_Details>`. It's not a matter of `List<T>` to `IEnumerable<T>`, it's what type those collections hold.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is self explanatory. Your view is strongly typed to a collection of `Error_Details` objects.Your current code is generating `IQueryable<bool>` as the type of `error_Summaries` variable and you are later calling the `ToList()` on that, which will generate a list of boolean values(`List<bool>`).

Your view is expecting something(`IEnumerable<Error_Details>`) and your action method is passing something else(`List<bool>`), hence getting that type mismatch exception!

You need to pass a collection of `Error_Details` objects to the view. I assume you wanted to pass a filtered list of items which is has the same BOL value as your `bolnumber` parameter. You can use the LINQ `Where` method to do the filtering.

```
var items =  db.Error_Details.Where(a=>a.BOL == bolnumber).ToList();
return PartialView("~/Views/Error_Details/Index.cshtml",items);
```

Assuming the `BOL` property on `Error_Details` class is of `string` type.

Comment: Hi Shyju, How do  I filter the result using the bolnumber?

Comment: See the update i posted to the answer.

Comment: Sorry to bug you again, could you take a peek at -https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47640100/property-on-a-model-could-not-be-set-to-a-system-decimal-value-you-must-set-t